# How to get the number of replies from a comment with RestFB

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, java-8, restfb

I need to get the comments with your replies for all nodes owned by authenticated users.

I have it in the following way with stream java 8:

```
private Stream<Comment> getCommentsByObjectAfterThan(final FacebookClient facebookClient, final String objectId, final Date startDate, User user) {

        Connection<Comment> commentConnection
                = facebookClient.fetchConnection(objectId + "/comments", Comment.class);

        return StreamUtils.asStream(commentConnection.iterator())
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .flatMap(comment
                        -> StreamUtils.concat(
                        getCommentsByObjectAfterThan(facebookClient, comment.getId(), startDate, user), comment)
                )
                .filter(comment -> !comment.getFrom().getId().equals(user.getId()) &&
                        (startDate != null ? comment.getCreatedTime().after(startDate) : true));
    }
```

I need to optimize the second flapMap that creates a stream with the top-level **comment and its replies**.

Clearly it would have to do so:

```
.flatMap(comment ->  comment.getCommentCount() > 0 ? StreamUtils.concat(
             getCommentsByObjectAfterThan(facebookClient,comment.getId(), startDate, user), comment) : Stream.of(comment))
```

The problem is that it `comment.getCommentCount()` always returns 0 even though the comments have replies.

How can i fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the line

```
Connection<Comment> commentConnection
            = facebookClient.fetchConnection(objectId + "/comments", Comment.class);
```

to

```
Connection<Comment> commentConnection
            = facebookClient.fetchConnection(objectId + "/comments", Comment.class, Parameter.with("fields","comment_count");
```

Then you get the `comment_count` field of the comment.